# "Repair or modification" close change

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Short and simple: I propose that the current close vote option regarding repair be expanded to cover modification as well. So:

> Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired.

becomes:

> Questions on the repair or modification of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting or analysis steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device.

Comment: Why? Modification involves an element of design, which is what we're all about.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I'm not saying that the asker needs to be able to figure out the modification themselves, but they do need to be able present the necessary information for others to even attempt to help them with it. Just saying "modify this black box for me" does no one any favors.